# Scheme missing linux wget

Tags: sh, wget, odoo

**While trying to install Odoo on Ubuntu 18.04, I ran into an error after running the following command:**

```
sudo wget -O wkhtmltox.tar.xz \ https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
```

**The error said**:

```
 https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz: Scheme missing
```

Please help me if you know the answer to my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find all the releases at:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases

Your command fails due to an extra `\` before `https://`. Try this:

```
sudo wget -O wkhtmltox.tar.xz https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
```

FYI, There are some issues with wkhtmltopdf that seems to be solved in early versions like 0.12.5
See bug references at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/19160

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2711#issuecomment-389429960

Comment: Sure!! happy to help